# Graphical Visualization of XML data

Tags: python, xml, neo4j

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<rebase>
   <Organism>
     <Name>Aminomonas paucivorans</Name>
       <Enzyme>M1.Apa12260I</Enzyme>
         <Motif>GGAGNNNNNGGC</Motif>
       <Enzyme>M2.Apa12260I</Enzyme>
         <Motif>GGAGNNNNNGGC</Motif>
   </Organism>
   <Organism>
    <Name>Bacillus cellulosilyticus</Name>
       <Enzyme>M1.BceNI</Enzyme>
         <Motif>CCCNNNNNCTC</Motif>
       <Enzyme>M2.BceNI</Enzyme>
         <Motif>CCCNNNNNCTC</Motif>
   </Organism>
</rebase>
```

I want to visualize this XML data into a graphical format. The connectivity is such that a lot of `enzymes` can contain common `motifs` but no `organims` can have similar `enzymes`. I looked at [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) but I dont think it has what im looking for. I was really excited with the visualization `neo4j` seems to provide but i will need to learn it from scratch. However I havent come across any good tutorials for importing or creating a graph in `neo4j` via XML datasets. I know in the world of programming anything is possible so I wanted to know the possible ways I could import my data (preferably using `python`) to a neo4j database to visualize it.

**UPDATE**

I tried following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25113853/3133885) (second answer under this question). I created the 2 `CSV` files that he suggested. However the query has a lot of syntax errors , such as :

1. `Invalid input 'S': expected 'n/N' (line 6, column 2)
   "USING PERIODIC COMMIT"`
2. `WITH is required between CREATE and LOAD CSV (line 6, column 1)
   "MATCH (o:Organism { name: csvLine.name}),(m:Motif { name: csvLine.motif})"`

My `cypher` query skill are extremely limited and i couldnt get any `imports` to work so fixing the query by myself is proving to be really difficult. Any help will be greately appreciated

Answer (score 2):

There is also a series of posts how to import XML into Neo4j.

- http://supercompiler.wordpress.com/2014/07/22/navigating-xml-graph-using-cypher/
- http://supercompiler.wordpress.com/2014/04/06/visualizing-an-xml-as-a-graph-neo4j-101/

First you should model how your data should look like as a graph, which entities do you need for your use-cases and which semantic connections.

In general if you can load the data in python, you can use py2neo or neo4jrestclient (see https://neo4j.com/developer/python/) to import your data into your model.

Answer (score 1):

for this i would suggest to use directly [gephi](http://gephi.github.io/) . at least a year ago it worked flawlessly, it supports xml/csv data format import directly and there is no need to use `neo4j` as pre-processor.

**edit**

oh, i see now, i though the connections are already included. in this case, you must create all the data from xml as a separate node - new node for each `enzyme` and `motif` and also for each `organism`(with a parameter `name`). those `enzyme` nad `motif` nodes must be unique - i.e. no duplicates. when creating an `organism` node, you connect the `organism` to its `enzyme` and `motif` nodes by a relationship. after this is done, querying/visualizing  similar nodes is no problem, since common nodes share at least one of the `enzyme/motif`.

i don't know any smart way to import data `xml` to neo4j, but you should have no problem to convert it into two `csv` files. the format of that csv would than be:

first file:

```
name,enzyme
Aminomonas paucivorans,M1.Apa12260I
Aminomonas paucivorans,M2.Apa12260I
Bacillus cellulosilyticus,M1.BceNI
Bacillus cellulosilyticus,M2.BceNI
```

second file (i don't understand why the `motif` is duplicite thought):

```
name,motif
Aminomonas paucivorans,GGAGNNNNNGGC
Aminomonas paucivorans,GGAGNNNNNGGC
Bacillus cellulosilyticus,CCCNNNNNCTC
Bacillus cellulosilyticus,CCCNNNNNCTC
```

now we are going to do the [import](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html?_ga=1.36841891.2043392826.1399556152), which creates **unique** nodes and relationships (thus the above duplicite `motifs` would transfer just into 1 unique relation) (if neccessary, it is possible to have multiple relationships to the same `motif` node, too):

(i'm not sure with this import but it should work):

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file1.csv" AS csvLine
MATCH (o:Organism { name: csvLine.name}),(e:Enzyme { name: csvLine.enzyme})
CREATE (o)-[:has_enzyme]->(e) //or maybe CREATE UNIQUE?

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file2.csv" AS csvLine
MATCH (o:Organism { name: csvLine.name}),(m:Motif { name: csvLine.motif})
CREATE (o)-[:has_motif]->(m) //or maybe CREATE UNIQUE?
```

this shall create th graph with 2 organism nodes, 4 enzyme nodes and 2 motif nodes. each organism node should than have a relationship to its enzymes and motifs. after this is done, you can move forward to the visualization part described at the beginning.

Comment: could you elaborate on the process? I ve tried to google it but it says I have to build my own interpreter

Comment: thank you so much for your time and help. Ill try it out and let you know if I encounter any problems.

Comment: Ifinally got back to this project . I have the two CSV files as you said but your query throws up a lot of syntax errors

Comment: i wrote it by heart and didnt test it, it needs some tweaks. but you should get the point though.

Comment: I looked up the issues and dint get any real solution to it. Specially on the line `USING PERIODIC COMMIT`